# I am getting � Question mark in triangle and Â from database in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on PHP PDO and MYSQL database. I was working on localhost xampp but after uploading on live server I got � sign and Â sign with text. It's not showing any issue on localhost xampp.
Like - This is my text . Â I am checking � .

```
content longtext    utf8_general_ci
```

I am using collation utf8_general_ci in PHPMYADMIN.
I have tried -

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");?>
```

It removes � sign, not Â sign.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
```

And it removes Â not �
This my meta -

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am using PHP PDO connection like this -

```
private $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::DBHOST . ';dbname=' . self::DBNAME.';utf8';
        public function __construct(){
            try{
                $this->dbConnection = new PDO($this->dsn, self::DBUSER, self::DBPASS);
                $this->dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
                //echo 'Database connected successfully';
            }
```

Is there any issue on the live server or I am doing any mistakes?

Comment: 1. check collation in your hosting server mysql db pls. 2. also use `$mysqli -> set_charset("utf8");` (say for mysqli) and use similar for PDO ,such as $conn->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

Comment: I am not using MySQLI. I am using PHP PDO.

Comment: so use PDO syntax pls

Comment: Thank you Ken Lee . I have placed UTF here and it's working cool .  `$this->dbConnection = new PDO($this->dsn, self::DBUSER, self::DBPASS,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Comment: Great to know that you have fixed the problem. Have a nice day !

Comment: This might already be answered at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)